# How to Install openjdk-6-jre on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04

I was trying to install openjdk-6-jre this arfternoon for URSim using `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre` but I got the following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-6-jre is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
icedtea-netx:i386 icedtea-netx-common icedtea-netx

E: Package 'openjdk-6-jre' has no installation candidate
```

When I try install URSim using openjdk-8-jdk I get the following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libjava3d-jni' for glob 'libjava3d-*'
Note, selecting 'libjava3d-java-doc' for glob 'libjava3d-*'
Note, selecting 'libjava3d-java' for glob 'libjava3d-*'
Note, selecting 'ttf-dejavu-core' for glob 'ttf-dejavu*'
Note, selecting 'ttf-dejavu-extra' for glob 'ttf-dejavu*'
Note, selecting 'ttf-dejavu' for glob 'ttf-dejavu*'
Package openjdk-6-jre is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  icedtea-netx:i386 icedtea-netx-common icedtea-netx

E: Package 'openjdk-6-jre' has no installation candidate
```

I also tried to download Java 1.6 from Oracle and installing that, but when I try install URSim it doesn't seem to recognize it.

Any help on updating mirrors? or finding the correct installation file and the path setup to get this working?

Comment: Is it hardwired to need Java 6?

Comment: Why don't you want to install a recent Java8? Java 9 is already knocking at the doors. (I don't know URSim). With `javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6` you may compile for compatibility with older versions - I don't know whether 1.6 is supported.

Comment: It seems to require java 6. I was following some different instructions before using java 8 but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by following the instructions here:
https://github.com/arunavanag591/ursim

Turns out I just needed to change the dependency from openjdk-6-jre to openjdk-8-jre and everything appears to be working fine.

Comment: changing the version might not is what the question intends to ask